# Does not name a type error, when trying to assign outputs to see pointer and reference outputs

Tags: c++, pointers, error-handling, reference, output

Hello I'm trying to find the outputs of either reference or pointers but I 
encounter a name type error:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    auto j,h,n,m,k;
    auto j = 19;
    auto h = 12;
    auto &n = j;
    auto *m = &h;
    auto *k = h;
    cout << "j=" <<j <<"\n";
    cout << "h=" << h <<"\n";
    cout << "n= " << &n << endl;
    cout << "m= " << &h << endl;
    cout << "k= " << *k << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you think this should work: `auto j,h,n,m,k;`?

Comment: What error message do you get from the compiler? It should give you an idea what's wrong ...

Comment: Matthias, the same for each line of auto i see name type error

Answer (score 1):

auto can only be used when you have a specific type on the right size of the definition.

Because you don't use an assignment of a specific type in th e line

```
auto j,h,n,m,k;
```

You get an error. Further more, n,m,k are used later in the program, so you are not allowed to define them twice.
The program will work if you give the variables a specific type and ommit the variable declaration n,m,k in the first line. Like

```
int j,h;
```

Answer (score 0):

**auto** is only allowed if you initialise at the same time.
so line **auto j,h,n,m,k** is wrong and "auto &n=j" is illegal.

Comment: `auto &n = j;` is OK (if the `auto j,h,n,m,k` line is deleted)